# using tkinter for GUI

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

How would I go about wrapping this text in a GUI? I am fairly new to python and programming in general and well I wrote this converter as a first project. I now want to wrap the project in a GUI but when I started reading about tkinter it looks as though I would have to rewrite my entire code. Is it possible to wrap a GUI around this without completely rewriting it?

```
 __Version__ = 0.1
import time
import os
from tkinter import Tk

line_break = "==========_Number_in_Inches_=========="
MM_break = "==========_Enter_MM_To_Convert_=========="
sys_Error = "ValueError, Could not recognize input as a number" 
Inches = float(25.4)

def main():
    while True:
        os.system('CLS')
        print("Welcome to the converter")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("What would you like to do?")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("Enter Convert MM or Convert Surface")
        function = (input())
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if function in('Convert','convert'):
            con()
        elif function in('Surface', 'surface', 'RA', 'ra', 'Ra'):
            surf()
        elif function in('end', 'kill', 'quit', 'End', 'Kill', 'Quit'):
            print("Goodbye")
            time.sleep(1.00)
            os.system('CLS')
            time.sleep(1.00)
            break       
        elif function in('help', 'Help'):
            help()
        else:
            print(sys_Error)
            time.sleep(1.0)

def con():
    while True:
        print("Return = Main Menu, Surface = RA Conversion")
        print(MM_break)
        number = (input())
        if number in('Return', 'return'):
            break
        elif number in('Surface', 'surface', 'Ra', 'RA', 'ra'):
                surf()
        elif number in('help', 'Help'):
        help()
        elif number in('end', 'kill', 'quit', 'End', 'Kill', 'Quit'):
            break
        else:
            try:
                float(number)
            except ValueError:
                print(sys_Error)
                break
            else:
                float_number = float(number)
                Convert = float_number/Inches
                Results_3 = ("%.3f" % Convert)
                Results_4 = ("%.4f" % Convert)
                print(line_break)
                print(" ")
                print('\t', Results_3)
                print('\t', Results_4)
                print(line_break)
                print(" ")
                r = Tk()
                r.withdraw()
                r.clipboard_clear()
                r.clipboard_append(Results_3)

def surf():
    while True:
        print("Please enter Surface Finish")
        print("or type return to return to main menu")
        surface = (input())
        if surface in('Return', 'return'):
            break
        elif surface in('Convert', 'convert'):
            con()
        elif surface in('help', 'Help'):
            help()
        elif surface in('end', 'kill', 'quit', 'End', 'Kill', 'Quit'):
            break   
        else:
            try:
                float(surface)
            except ValueError:
                print(sys_Error)
                time.sleep(1.0)
                break
            else:
                float_surface = float(surface)
                RA_convert = (float_surface/Inches) * 1000
                Results = float(RA_convert)
                RA_results = ("%.0f" % Results)
                print(RA_results)
                r = Tk()
                r.withdraw()
                r.clipboard_clear()
                r.clipboard_append(RA_results)

def help():
    while True:
        print('\t' "If you are having trouble")
        print('\t' "Make sure you are prompting the program")
        print('\t' "to enter etiher MM conversion mode")
        print('\t' "or Surface Conversion mode")
        print('\t' "by entering Convert or Surface")
        print('\t' "when prompted at startup")
        print('\t' "make sure that you are entering a number")
        print('\t' "or a recognized command")
        print('\t' "The list of commands are as follows")
        print('\t' "help = Displays help message")
        print('\t' "end = Ends the program")
        print('\t' "(also try End, quit, Quit, kill, Kill)")
        print('\t' "Convert = MM Conversion mode")
        print('\t' "Surface or Ra = Surface conversion mode")
        print('\t' "If you are still having problems contact")
        print('\t' "Daniel Granado")
        print('\t' "at Dan_granado@pennunited.com")
        time.sleep(4.0)
        print("Press enter to return to main menu")
        reload = input()
        break

main()
```

Comment: Your indentation is messed up -- your method definitions are not indented properly under the `def`s.

Comment: @BryanOakley thanks for pointing that out. I just copied the code from my text editor and pasted it in. It must not have formatted right.

Answer (score 0):

In some ways you could but it would prove difficult. You could use buttons or a menubar to do the commands and then labels to do the text. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:** No

You technically can but you will have to change a LOT of your code.You would have to use Labels, buttons etc and since you are a begginer you should learn tkinter by building an app from scratch.